# PHP and MySQL: How to get all database entries form two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following code which gets data from a table entry and displays some html for each entry. It works fine but i want it to display html for the entries in that table AND another table. I could just duplicate this code and change it a bit to get the entries in a different table but that creates another problem, all the entries from the second table would start at the end of the entree list from the first table. How can I display the entries from both table in the order of most relevant to what the user types in? Here is my code that just displays entries from the first table in order of when they were inserted into the table. Can someone tell me how to display all the entries from two different tables in order of relavace to a user search query? My code so far, I have not been able to get much further than this.

```
$pagesQuery  = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM(`posts`) WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%' OR `descrip` LIKE '%{$terms}%'");
$pageNum = ceil(mysql_result($pagesQuery, 0)/5);
$start = (($page-1)*5);

$currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%' OR `descrip` LIKE '%{$terms}%' LIMIT $start, 5"); 


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
    //recieve relevant data.
    $title = $row[0];
    $desc = $row[13];
    $ID = $row[6];
    $views = $row[3];
    $user = $row[7];
    $type = $row[15];
    //fetch the last id from accounts table.
    $fetchlast1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM allaccounts)");
    $lastrow1 = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast1);
    $lastid1 = $lastrow1[6];
    //acquire the username of postee.
    for ($i1=1; $i1 <= $lastid1; $i1++) { 
        $currentname1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=$user");
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($currentname1)) {
            $username1 = $row1[0];
        }
    }

    //Format Title, description and view count.
    $title2 = rtrim($title);
    $donetitle = str_replace(" ", "-", $title2);
    $donetitle1 = str_replace(".", "", $donetitle);
    $donetitle2 = str_replace("-", "-", $donetitle1);
    $donetitle3 = str_replace(":", "-", $donetitle2);
    $url = "articles/".$ID."/".$donetitle3."";

    $donetitle = strlen($title) > 40 ? substr($title,0,40)."..." : $title;
    $donedesc = '';

    if(strlen($desc) > 150) {
        $donedesc = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $desc, 150));
        $donedesc1 = $donedesc[0] . '...';                          
    } else {
        $donedesc1 = $desc;                         
    }
    $SRCIMG = '';
    $finviews = number_format($views, 0, '.', ',');
    if($type == '1'){
        $SRCIMG = "img/icons/video.png";
    } else {
        $SRCIMG = "img/icons/article.png";
    }
    //Give  results

    if($row[10] == null){
        $SRC = "img/tempsmall.jpg";
    }else{
        $SRC ="generateThumbnailSmall.php?id=$ID"; 
    }
    echo "<div id = \"feature\">
            <img src=\"$SRC\" alt = \"article thumbnail\" />
            <img src=\"$SRCIMG\" alt = \"icon\" id=\"icondisp\"/>
        </div>
        <div id = \"feature2\">
             <a href= \"$url\" id = \"titletext\" alt = \"article title\">$donetitle</a>
             <p id=\"resultuser\" >$username1</p>
             <p id=\"resultp\">$donedesc1</p>
             <a href = \"sendflag.php?title=$title&url=$url&id=$ID&userid=$user\" id = \"flag\" alt = \"flag\"><img src=\"img/icons/flag.png\"/></a><b id=\"resultview\">$finviews views</b> 
        </div>
        <div id = \"border\"></div>";        
}
```

Comment: `like` queries have no relevance score. You'd need to use a fulltext search to get that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you ought to use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to merge SELECT results from two or more tables.

So you query should look like this:

```
(SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%'
OR `descrip`  LIKE '%{$terms}%')
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM `posts2`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%'
OR `descrip` LIKE '%{$terms}%')
LIMIT $start, 5
```

Notice that number and names of columns in both SELECTS should be the same.

Comment: If having different column names, then?

Comment: Then you can give them the same alias in SELECT

Comment: For example: (SELECT title AS post FROM posts) UNION (SELECT caption AS post FROM articles)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try union ?

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%' OR `descrip` LIKE '%  {$terms}%' 
union
SELECT * FROM `otherposts table` WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$terms}%' OR `descrip` LIKE '%{$terms}%' 
order by yourRelevanceField
LIMIT $start, 5"
```

Comment: I have this but i keep getting errors: SELECT count(id) FROM(`posts`) union SELECT count(id) FROM(`videos`)

Comment: that's all of the count, you can just add these two numbers

Answer (score 0):

Actually it just hit me, I should probably create a new table called SearchElements where I store data needed for a search result. I would create a SearchElement each time an entree is added to either table. still dont understand relevance  yet though.

Comment: I understand that you **don't** have *enough reputation* to comment in question comment section. But, if you want to provide more info regarding question, please Update/Edit your question with your suggestions. Otherwise, you will lose all your reputation here itself when *downvotes* will come into picture. *~Just Saying*.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can go for UNION of two tables and try something like this

INSERT INTO table3 
SELECT * FROM tabel1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tabel2